# Cocoa - simple collada parser

Tags: xml, cocoa, parsing, collada

I´ve been researching a bit in the net but didnt find any Straightforward answer, i am looking for a simple way to Load Vertex and U/V data from a collada .dae file, i don´t need textures and normals for my application (for now) but i want it as lightweight&fast as possible. Any hints or existing solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with collada, but you might find my open source Cocoa parsing/tokenizing toolkit useful: http://parsekit.com